# Mongodb aggregate with $geoNear Exception: geoNear command failed: { ok: 0.0, errmsg: \"can't get query runner\"

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, geospatial

I am trying to run $geoNear with mongodb aggregate and getting the below error. I tried to find the issue but I am unable to. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Error -

```
aggregate failed: {
"errmsg": "exception: geoNear command failed: { ok: 0.0, errmsg: \"can't get query runner\" }",
"code": 16604,
"ok": 0
} at /Users/waseemquamar/.mongorc.js:82
```

Query -

```
db.retailers.aggregate([
{
 $geoNear: {
    near: { type: "Point", coordinates: [ -73.99279 , 40.719296 ] },
    distanceField: "dist.calculated",
    maxDistance: 2,
    includeLocs: "dist.location",
    num: 5,
    spherical: true
 }
}
```

Index - db.retailers.getIndexes();

```
[
{
"v": 1,
"key": {
  "_id": 1
},
"name": "_id_",
"ns": "hw_development.retailers"
},
{
"v": 1,
"key": {
  "geolocation": "2d"
},
"name": "geolocation_2d",
"ns": "hw_development.retailers",
"background": true,
"safe": null
}
]
```